# Looking for videos about Shodokan Aikido Basic Techniques

Tags: aikido, shodokan

I just become a member of Shodokan aikido.  As there are many members with different level, I am also taught many techniques in one session. It seems to be difficult for me to remember these techniques. It is really confusing. I cannot catch the important points as well as the 3D orientation and movements.

I need a video that can be played as many as I want to review the techniques.

## Question

Are there any free or commercial videos explaining the shodokan basic techniques in easy-to-learn ways?

Comment: [Meta question about the Shodokan tag](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/q/496/82).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly normal. Remember that instructors do not expect you to get it right, they expect you to try. ☺ Your best bet is to keep going to classes and try everything. The most important part of any Shodokan lesson is the first half an hour. That is the bit you have to concentrate on the most.

Many shodokan instructors, following Nariyama, are unkeen on being captured on video. There has been in the past too much criticism and tension from people looking at badly filmed videos and becoming experts in the technique show. So, you will not find a definitive guide.

However, there are several resources you can use:

- [Shodokan hombu](http://en.shodokanaikido.com/) has a blog (or news sections) that contains some videos. You can subscribe to their [RSS feed](http://en.shodokanaikido.com/feed/).
- There are [several Shodokan Aikido Youtube channels](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=youtube%20shodokan%20aikido%20channel&ia=videos) as well as Facebook pages you an follow.
- Both [Allbright](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Aikido-Randori-Reconciliation-Opposing-Forces/dp/1861264984/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1489149326&sr=8-1&keywords=scott%20allbright) and [Nariyama](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Aikido-Randori-Tetsuro-Nariyama/dp/0956620507/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1489149299&sr=8-3&keywords=nariyama) have written books which are must have. There is a master course DVD/book that you can get from hombu, but you will need to source it directly from the instructors. Best go via your instructor team. It used to be instructor only but that might have changed.
- Otherwise, you could spend some time googling for Scott Allbright, Phil Newcomb, Joe Adams, Satoru Tsutchiya, Mike MacCavish, Ryuichi Omori, Sakia, and of course Tetsuro Nariyama. Most of what you will get are demonstrations but more often than not, you can find extract from seminars where they teach a given set of techniques.

Comment: Regarding "There is a master course DVD/book that you can get from hombu", how do you know this?

Comment: @SingleFighter I have a copy which I got from Nariyama-san.